# Make DIV take space of another DIV which is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am building a quiz that is going to generate a set of 10 questions of out a pool of 40.

My idea is to use a generated array of 10 numbers and hide them using JQuery. The JQuery would `.hide()` the questions that aren't needed and the would be displayed in the default format.

I need the divs of the questions that are selected to take up the spaces left by the hidden divs. Since the pool is massive, is there a practical way to do this?

Note: I don't have the JQuery done at the moment.

[image]

[image]

```css
 /* Quiz Styling */

.quiz-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 50%;
}

.header{
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    
}

.question{
    margin-top: 10px;
}

ul{
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#qu1{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <div class="header">
        <h1> You have made it into the quiz!</h1>
        <br>
        <p>You are about to go through a series of 10 MCQs. <br>
        At the end of the questions, you will obtain your marks!<br>
        Good Luck and Have Fun! <br>
        Once ready, press the button below!</p>

    </div>
    <div class="quiz-wrapper">


        <button id="quiz_start" class="quiz_start">Click me to start!</button>
        <div class="quiz">

            <div class="question" id="qu1"><span class="qu_no"></span>A game where player fight in an arena-style environment is referred as __________?
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="one_a" name="gametype" value="one_a" required>
                        <label for="one_a">MMO</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="one_b" name="gametype" value="one_b" required>
                        <label for="one_b">RPG</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="one_c" name="gametype" value="one_c" required>
                        <label for="one_c">Open World</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="one_d" name="gametype" value="one_d" required>
                        <label for="one_d">FPS</label>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="question" id="qu2"><span class="qu_no"></span>What is the name of the most recent graphics card series released by nVidia?
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="two_a" name="gpucards" value="two_a" required>
                        <label for="two_a">RTX 3000 Series</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="two_b" name="gpucards" value="two_b" required>
                        <label for="two_b">Intel i5</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="two_c" name="gpucards" value="two_c" required>
                        <label for="two_c">Jolt Series</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" id="two_d" name="gpucards" value="two_d" required>
                        <label for="two_d">GTX 1000 Series</label>
                    </li>

                </ul>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that if any element have been hidden by JQuery `.hide()`, the element has `display: none` style, so nothing in this element cannot be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Simply have a set size for the whole div.

The hidden questions will have display:none and will therefore not take up any space, you can give all questions something like `height: 100%;` and they will always fill out the big div, or if they also have a set size (as in set by pixels, or vh etc.) the questions will just keep appearing as in a list.

Not sure if this answers your question or if there is something else you are trying to do, do you mean that you always want the next question on top? In that case I would not have the questions as a part of the div from the beginning, but rather have them in an array in JavaScript and then use the jquery function .prepend() to add them as the first element to the div.